# View loads before $scope values are assigned

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I've come to this problem were my view loads before $scope params are assigned and this is caused by $http service call taking some time before response is achived.

This leaves me with dropdown boxes being unsync with url params on page reload...

Is there anyway to reload these $scope params or wait til they get values before rendering the view? I would like the easiest solution to this as Im yet farily new to angularjs.
Just give me a hint if more info is needed!

Here's some of the code...

**Route**

```
angular.module('app', ['ngRoute', 'app.controller', 'app.service', 'app.filter'])
.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/order/:id', {
            templateUrl: '../../App_AngularJs/partials/specificOrder.htm',
            controller: 'orderController',
            reloadOnSearch: true
        })
        .when('/orderitem/:id', {
            templateUrl: '../../App_AngularJs/partials/orderItem/orderItem.htm',
            controller: 'orderItemController',
            reloadOnSearch: true
        })
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: '../../App_AngularJs/partials/searchOrder.htm',
            controller: 'ordersController',
            reloadOnSearch: false
            //Use some resolve here!? How!?
        });
}
```

**Controller**

```
var orderContrl = angular.module('app.controller', ['angularTreeview', 'ui.bootstrap'])
.controller('ordersController', [
    '$scope', '$routeParams', '$location', '$filter', '$modal', '$log', 'orderService',
    function ($scope, $routeParams, $location, $filter, $modal, $log, orderService) {
        init();

        function init() {
            $scope.searchtext = $routeParams.search || '';
            $scope.page = $routeParams.page || 1;
            $scope.take = $routeParams.take || 10;
            $scope.status = $routeParams.status || -1;
            $scope.group = $routeParams.group || -1;
            $scope.type = $routeParams.type || -1;
            $scope.category = $routeParams.category || -1;
            $scope.selectedOrganisation = "Knoc LK";

            getOrders(true);
            getFilters(true);
        }

        function getFilters(reloadPage) {
            orderService.queryOrderAllDropdown()
                .then(function (response) {
                    $scope.orderGroup = response.OrderGroups;
                    $scope.orderStatus = response.OrderStatus;
                    $scope.orderType = response.OrderTypes;
                    $scope.orderPackageCategory = response.ProductPackageCategories;
                    $scope.orderAllCategory = response.ProductItemCategories;

                    //Sets type and shows different categories depending on type chosen
                    getCategory();

                    //Trying to reassign the values but still nothing...
                    if (reloadPage) {
                        angular.forEach($scope.orderStatus, function (value) {
                            if ($routeParams.status == value.ID)
                                $scope.status = value.ID;
                        });
                        //Trying to reassign the values but still nothing...
                        $scope.group = $scope.group;
                    }

                },
                function (errorMessage) {
                    $scope.error = errorMessage;
                });
        }
```

**Service**

```
 angular.module('app.service', [])
.service('orderService', ['$http', '$q', function ($http, $q) {

    this.queryOrderAllDropdown = function () {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        $http({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'GenericHandlers/HttpOrderService.ashx',
            method: 'GetOrderAllDropdown',
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' }
        }).success(function (data) {
            deferred.resolve(data);
        }).error(function () {
            deferred.reject("An error occured while fetching data");
        });

        return deferred.promise;
    },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a Resolver to fetch the data from the backend. Adding a "resolve" to the $routeProvider will fetch the data before the controller takes control. Check out [this blog post](http://blog.brunoscopelliti.com/show-route-only-after-all-promises-are-resolved) for a similar example.

Comment: I tried this and works good, still my dropdowns doesnt get set to correct values. Any figure?

Comment: Are you doing the Service operations also in the resolver. Basically all delayed operations can be done there so when it gets to the Controller, it can just use those values and fill in the templates. Can you post a jsfiddle if its still an issue.